# php strcmp with file data

Tags: php, file, strcmp

I want to read a csv file exported from Excel and store it in a MySQL table. Columns are either ordinary strings, integers, or dates. Since the dates in the csv file are seen as string but I want them stored with the MySQL DATE type I have parallel arrays of table field names and date types. I have an outer loop on rows and inner loop on columns. In the inner loop I  compare column data type with "DATE" so I can use a PHP date formatting function to recast the string '1/21/2014' to the MySQL DateTime format.

The problem: strcasecmp($colTypes[$iCol],"DATE") == 0 never evaluates to TRUE even though $colTypes[$iCol] echos "DATE". I believe this has to do with the way php is storing the string "DATE" vs the way it's stored in the file read.

Here's the code:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',', '"')) !== FALSE)
{
$num = count($data);
echo "There are : " . $num . " fields in line " . $row . "<br />";
if ($row > 0) { // Skip header row
//  Build a CSV list of column values
$values = '';  
for ($iCol=0; $iCol < $num; $iCol++) { 
if ($iCol == 0) {$sep = '\'';} // this avoid leading comma
else {$sep = ', \'';}
$Type = $colTypes[$iCol];
if (strcasecmp($Type,"DATE") == 0){ 

//...
//...
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Ed

Answer (score 0):

you could just do:

```
$Type = trim(strtolower($colTypes[$iCol]));
if ($Type == "date"){
    ....
}
```

and try doing this and see what you get:

```
echo strcasecmp($Type,"DATE");
```

to see if you get `0` or not

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I guess the string in $colTypes has some extra bytes at the end?

Comment: @EdS if that worked then you could mark it as Accepted Answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

After you get the date from the database just use this function:

```
$date1 = new DateTime($date_from_db);
$date2 = $date1->format('d-m-y');

if (strcasecmp($Type,$date2) == 0){...}
```

I checked it , and it worked for me.

Comment: I used MySQL and excel 2010. I Saved excel sheet as csv file. And I had a date in MySQL table. You just need to convert date stored in database as I showed.